# 2d standard assets prefab characterRobotBoy jumped into the boxCollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the standard 2d assets to learn developing 2d game with Unity, and I place a sprite with box-collider-2d, and choose the default standard assets `CharacterRobotBoy` to mess around with.

But I find that if I jumped and it's highly likely that the character will jump *into* the sprite which was intended to be made as a ground, but this will not happen every time. hope could get some help with that.

find the problem hard to describe and upload [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ca4TY965z5Q&feature=youtu.be) on youtue

[image]

[image]

### EDIT

will just paste the script from the demo asset as required.

File `PlatformerCharacter2D.cs`

```
  using System;
    using UnityEngine;

    namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
    {
        public class PlatformerCharacter2D : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [SerializeField] private float m_MaxSpeed = 10f;                    // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.
            [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                  // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
            [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;  // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
            [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                 // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
            [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                  // A mask determining what is ground to the character

            private Transform m_GroundCheck;    // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
            const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
            private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
            private Transform m_CeilingCheck;   // A position marking where to check for ceilings
            const float k_CeilingRadius = .01f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
            private Animator m_Anim;            // Reference to the player's animator component.
            private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
            private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.

            private void Awake()
            {
                // Setting up references.
                m_GroundCheck = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
                m_CeilingCheck = transform.Find("CeilingCheck");
                m_Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
                m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            }


            private void FixedUpdate()
            {
                m_Grounded = false;

                // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
                // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
                Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
                for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                        m_Grounded = true;
                }
                m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", m_Grounded);

                // Set the vertical animation
                m_Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            }


            public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
            {
                // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
                if (!crouch && m_Anim.GetBool("Crouch"))
                {
                    // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
                    if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
                    {
                        crouch = true;
                    }
                }

                // Set whether or not the character is crouching in the animator
                m_Anim.SetBool("Crouch", crouch);

                //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
                if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
                {
                    // Reduce the speed if crouching by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                    move = (crouch ? move*m_CrouchSpeed : move);

                    // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
                    m_Anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

                    // Move the character
                    m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move*m_MaxSpeed, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

                    // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
                    if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
                    {
                        // ... flip the player.
                        Flip();
                    }
                        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
                    else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
                    {
                        // ... flip the player.
                        Flip();
                    }
                }
                // If the player should jump...
                if (m_Grounded && jump && m_Anim.GetBool("Ground"))
                {
                    // Add a vertical force to the player.
                    m_Grounded = false;
                    m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
                    m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
                }
            }


            private void Flip()
            {
                // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
                m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

                // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
                Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
                theScale.x *= -1;
                transform.localScale = theScale;
            }
        }
    }
```

Script `Platformer2DUserControl.cs`

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platformer2DUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D m_Character;
        private bool m_Jump;


        private void Awake()
        {
            m_Character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Read the inputs.
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
            m_Character.Move(h, crouch, m_Jump);
            m_Jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does your character also contains a rigidbody2d?

Comment: yes, it contains a rigidbody 2d

Comment: can you share the jump script you use?

Comment: Hi, Ido, thanks for replying , I have just pasted the script for the player as required. and for the record, I just usethe standard 2d assert shipped with Unity IDE, You may find and test it in your own environment, cause I really don't know how to describe this problem clearly :-(

Comment: what happens is the ground is not high enough and the force of the landing is strong that it actually went through the ground and not back up, try to increase the height of the collider of the ground

Comment: I tried tweak the collider(box-collider that contains the ground sprite) to a more large one, but it seems the player still will fall into the ground.